# Using Multiple GTR, LEQ, etc "if" statements in Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, set

I have a batch file that asks the user to input a specific number. If the number is in between a given set of numbers, it goes to that label. However, say the user puts `100` it goes right to `:smallsip`

All in all, I'm trying to make it so that if the user types a number within a specific range (I.E 30-99) it goes to a specific label. Any suggestions?

```
:getadrink
cls
echo How many sips will Jackie Chan drink?

set /p numberofsips=Type Number of Sips Here: 

if %numberofsips% LSS 0 goto waitwhat
if %numberofsips% GEQ 1 goto smallsip
if %numberofsips% GEQ 10 goto plenty
if %numberofsips% GEQ 30 goto toomuch
if %numberofsips% GEQ 100 goto waytoomuch

:waitwhat
cls
echo what
pause
:smallsip
cls
echo small sips
pause
:plenty
cls
echo plenty
pause
:toomuch
cls
echo too much!
pause
:waytoomuch
cls
echo WAY TOO MUCH
pause
```

P.S. I've been lurking around numerous posts on here, getting help for something I'm creating with Batch. Yes, I know batch is outdated, but I just seem to like it as I have discovered it about 2 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statements in your code work correctly, but your logic is wrong. For instance, when you type a number `50`, the condition `%numberofsips% GEQ 1` is already met, so the following `if` statements will never be reached. To solve this, simply reverse their order.

Another problem is, that you fall into fall into code which you do not want to be executed. For example, when the portion `:smallsip` has finished (and you confirmed the `pause`), execution continues at `:plenty` unintentionally. To avoid that, you will need a `goto` to jump somewhere else or an `exit /B` to leave the batch script.

Here is a fixed code:

```
:getadrink
cls
echo How many sips will Jackie Chan drink?

:askforsips
set numberofsips=0
set /p numberofsips=Type Number of Sips Here: 

if %numberofsips% GEQ 100 goto waytoomuch
if %numberofsips% GEQ 30 goto toomuch
if %numberofsips% GEQ 10 goto plenty
if %numberofsips% GEQ 1 goto smallsip
goto waitwhat

:waitwhat
cls
echo what?
pause
goto askforsips
:smallsip
cls
echo small sips
pause
exit /B
:plenty
cls
echo plenty
pause
exit /B
:toomuch
cls
echo too much!
pause
goto askforsips
:waytoomuch
cls
echo WAY TOO MUCH
pause
goto askforsips
```

These are the things that I changed:

- the order of `if` queries is reversed;
- the `if %numberofsips% LSS 0` query is removed, so `:waitwhat` is executed if the entered value is zero or less; in your code, `:waitwhat` was also executed in case the value was zero as none of the conditions were met; the final (lonely) `goto waitwhat` is not required here, but it is more obvious what happens;
- a new label `:askforsips` is introduced to allow another user input in case an invalid value (zero or less) was given;
- variable `numberofsips` is now reset before the user prompt, because `set /P` keeps the former value if the user just presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>;
- every section from `:waitwhat` down to `:waytoomuch` is terminated explicitly, either by `goto askforsips` or by `exit /B`;

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test it when I get home. It's for a batch game I'm making called "Jackie Chan Goes to School" I won't go into details why, but it's from a part where Jackie Chan sees a water fountain, and drinking too much makes him sick. It's stupid, I know, but you get the point. Again, I'll test it when I get home. :)